# How to pass all events from one subject to another subject in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I would like to pass all items or the error from subject1 to subject2. What in my mind is something like this:

```
val subject1 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
val subject2 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()

subject1.subscribe(
    { subject2.onNext(it) },
    { subject2.onError(it) },
    { subject2.onComplete() },
    { subject2.onSubscribe(it)}
)
```

Is there any way that I can simplify this transformation? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Subject` implements `Observer` so you can do `subject1.subscribe(subject2)` to get the `onNext`, `onError`, and `onComplete` events. If you need to forward `onSubscribe` as well you could add a `doOnSubscribe()` call:

```
subject1
  .doOnSubscribe { subject2.onSubscribe(it) }
  .subscribe(subject2)
```

Comment: You don't need `doOnSubscribe` here explicitly, a subscription will and has to call `onSubscribe` exactly once for you.